# Failure state error using google map support fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm using Google map in my application in fragment and facing one problem.

I'm getting this error

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active
>   SupportMapFragment{212f6b1} has cleared index: -1"

when my mobile goes to sleep while fragment containing google map is active.
My code containing google map is here :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

public MapFragment() {
}

GoogleMap mgoogleMap;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("cycle","Mapfragment-created");
    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return RootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d("map", "OnMapReady");
    if (mgoogleMap == null)
        mgoogleMap = googleMap;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("cycle-mapfragment","onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("cycle-mapfragment", "onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    try {
        SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it remove this line

`fm.executePendingTransactions();`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mMapView = new SupportMapFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMapView).commit();
    //fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
```